# jquery event been called twice - dropkick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dropkick

So I have this problem where I have a dropdown and then I create it using dropkick.js. (I am just learning dropkick.js so I am now thinking that I misunderstood something.)

**The Problem**

When I bind an on change event like so

```
$('.pizza_size').on('change', 'select[name=pizza_size]', function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

The alert is called twice.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fso75va/)

My initial problem was that the select dropdown was changed dynamically, so the `$(".default").dropkick();` didn't apply anymore, so I created this dynamic selector above. (If there is a better way to bind the call dynamically than this please do tell! :D)

***Helpful information:*** (based on some of my debugging)

- The initial html/script was like this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fso75va/) where it created two dropdowns, (**though they dont seem to be related**)The one I create with code `<select>...</select>` and the one dropkick.js creates with the `class=dk_container dk_theme_default` class. So I commented this html to avoid this (in first fiddle), but it still seems to exist 2 select dropdowns!

Comment: Your fiddle does not work because you have added js file which has a dev path and you need to remove the dev path with the live one.

Comment: @Yunus should be working now :D

Comment: Yes I am trying to solve the issue.. I have another fiddle created for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue :

Inside your dropkick.js plugin you have select triggered twice.
Search for these lines inside your plugin

```
$select.trigger('change');
$select.val(value).trigger('change');
```

Comment the first line here

```
$select.trigger('change'); // comment this line in your dropkick.js file
```

and try. "The alert is called twice." this will be fixed.

Comment: Monkey-patching a plugin is not an ideal solution, but in this case there's not much else to do.

Answer (score 1):

You probably simply should use [the documented API](https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick) of dropkick.

```
$(function () {
    $('.default').dropkick({
        change: function () {
            alert("You selected " + $(this).val() + " for " + this.id + ".");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that is what I had but if i create a `.default` element dynamically this will not work

Comment: That's an argument. [Filing an issue against the dropkick repo](https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick/issues) would be in order, I guess. I'd classify that double invocation of the `change` event a bug.

Comment: The thing is I just got the project (about a month now) half way done, so I don't know if the previous guy changed the dropkick.js. Also I am using a quite old version of the library, so I don't think (if it ever existed) that it will still exist :). Thank you for your time :D

Comment: I was just wondering whether you might use an old version because the offending lines are nowhere to be found in the current version. I'd urge you to upgrade. Incompatibilities in your code are probably a lot easier to fix than bugs in the dropkick source.

Comment: Yeap, Upgrading seems like the sane thing to do. I just hope there aren't many differences in the functionality so it will be an easy transition :)

Comment: As far as my experience says that these lines which I have pointed out `$select.trigger('change');
$select.val(value).trigger('change');` were some manual changes in the plugin.